# "Side-By-Side" Visual Studio C++ Error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm creating my first program in Visual Studio C++ 2008, coming from VB.NET - and I found some nice source I'm learning from with some simple API's for uploading images.

It works PERFECTLY for me, so I went to Build > Build Solution, Wen't into my Debug folder, and found the .exe for it.

I sent it to a friend, and they receive the following error when opening it:

```
 The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.  
 Please set the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for 
 more detail.
```

I am new at this, so if there is a complicated solution, please take the time to do a step-by-step solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is probably missing the VC Redist file for Dev Studio 2008.

Google "vc redist 2008".

Also, he will not be able to test a debug build, because the debug runtime is only included with the compiler; there isn't a stand-alone installer for it. You'll need to rebuild your app in release.

Comment: Note that you cannot redistribute the Debug runtime, only the Release runtime—if Alex's friend does not have VS 2008 installed, then he will not be able to run the Debug build.

Comment: How do I Build as a Release? Can you explain?

Comment: There is a "Debug/Release" box in the toolbars. (It's in the Build toolbar; you might need to enable it if it has been hidden.)

Comment: Nope. I don't see it, I do see a Release folder, but not .exe - and I don't see a 'Debug/Release', or anything that has to do with Release in Build. Any ideas?

Comment: Right click in the toolbar area and make sure the "Build" toolbar is enabled.

Comment: @Adam: You can always link the CRT statically.